# how to access the urlpatterns in urls.py of project?

Tags: python, django

I can access the settings by `from django.conf import settings`, when i try to access the urlpatterns using the same way, but with no luck. How can i access the urlpatterns in my views?

Comment: `from app.urls import urlpatterns`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What exactly did you try? and why do you need to?

Answer (score 0):

If every app has its own `urls.py` module, you can access it's `urlpatterns` importing from app:

```
from myapp.urls import urlpatterns
```

If you want the urls form project:

```
from myproject.urls import urlpatterns
```